# ngx-daterangepicker-material - Cannot set model for single date picker when typing date in input box

Tags: angular, datepicker

I have created a form using ngx-daterangepicker-material with a single date picker.  I can set the date by selecting it from the calendar fine. However if I type the date in the box with my keyboard it is not recognized and the previous date that was set in the select box is used as the model value.  Is this possible, if so how can I achieve this?

Here is my directive in my page:

```
<label for="submissionTimeFromDate" class="col-sm-3 text-sm-right col-form-label">Submission Time From</label>
<div class="col-sm-4">
  <input type="text" id="submissionTimeFromDate" name="submissionTimeFromDate" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="filter.submissionTimeFromDate" class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-bottom: 8px" [singleDatePicker]="true" [autoApply]="true" [locale]="{format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}" />
</div>
```

Here is how this property is set in the model.  It has to be done this way due to a bug at https://github.com/fetrarij/ngx-daterangepicker-material/issues/141:

```
 this.filter.submissionTimeFromDate = {startDate: moment().subtract(2, 'months'), endDate: moment().subtract(2, 'months') }
```

So when I submit my form I output the date value using the console.

If I set the date using the calendar then the output in the console is correct as follows:

[image]

[image]

When I type the date in the input box and click 'Filter' I get the previous date in the console 28/03/2019 which is incorrect:

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue, did you figure it out?

Comment: In order to fix this I just added a keyup listener on my input box that updates the model when a value is entered in the text box as shown in my answer.

Comment: @sachman, could you please try to modify the code like this?

 <input type="text" [(ngModel)]="filter.submissionTimeFromDate" id="submissionTimeFromDate" name="submissionTimeFromDate" ngxDaterangepickerMd  class="form-control form-control-sm" style="margin-bottom: 8px" [singleDatePicker]="true" [autoApply]="true" [locale]="{format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}" />

Answer (score 1):

I managed to fix this by adding a keyup listener on my input box that updates the model when a value is entered in the text box

```
                <label for="submissionTimeFromDate" class="col-sm-3 text-sm-right col-form-label">Submission Time From</label>
                <div class="col-sm-4">
                    <input #submissionTimeFromDateInput type="text" id="submissionTimeFromDate" name="submissionTimeFromDate" ngxDaterangepickerMd [(ngModel)]="submissionTimeFromDate"
                           class="form-control form-control-sm"  style="margin-bottom: 8px" (keyup)="updateSubmissionTimeFromDateTextInput(submissionTimeFromDateInput.value)"
                           [singleDatePicker]="true" [autoApply]="true" [locale]="{format: 'DD/MM/YYYY'}" (datesUpdated)="clearSubmissionTimeFromDateTextInput()"/>
                </div>
```